# deleting item from array takes much time

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Inside my controller I have two functions, first allows me to add new item to array, second removes single item.

My whole controller looks like this:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
  $scope.questions = [{
    text: 'What is Your name?',
    files: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'file 1'
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'Question 2',
    files: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'file 1'
    }]
  }, {
    text: 'Question 3',
    files: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'file 1'
    }]
  }];

  $scope.selectedQuestionIndex = undefined;
  $scope.selectedQuestion = function(index) {
    if ($scope.selectedQuestionIndex !== index) {
      $scope.selectedQuestionIndex = index;
    } else {
      $scope.selectedQuestionIndex = undefined;
    }
  };

  $scope.addFile = function(question) {
    question.files.push({
      id: 2,
      name: 'file 2'
    });
  };
  $scope.deleteFile = function(question, file) {
    var index = question.files.indexOf(file);
    question.files.splice(index, 1);
  };
});
```

Adding new items is fast, but deleting takes much more time:
[image: delete delay]

Here is Plunker showing issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/YYxeHlubDk0VThmQNmw4?p=preview

My question is: How can I speed up removing files assigned to question (how should I optimize deleteFile function)?

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm using `ngClick` for both adding and deleting. Adding is fast, but deleting is slow. Delay from `ngClick` should affect both buttons?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, I takes more than that...

Comment: sorry about that... The delay is happening from angular side... after the `deleteFile` is called to render the UI

Comment: It's caused by ngAnimate and css transition times

Comment: @ArunPJohny So aren't there any options to make both work with same speed?

Comment: @charlietfl adding new item should have same effect? Is there a way to speed it?

Comment: adjust transition time in css

Comment: @charlietfl Silly me :/ After removing transition from CSS everything works as expected

Answer (score 2):

You can [disable animation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$animate#enabled) on specific element.

```
.directive('noAnimate', ['$animate', function (animate) {
    return function (scope, element) {
        animate.enabled(element, false); 
    };
}])
```

See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/8r54aoPsgnwaLd1YceIu?p=preview)